# Table losing right side when <tr> element removed using jQuery UI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, html-table

I have a table in a `div` that looks like this:

```
<div id='lastInsert'>  
    <h5>Last <span id='quantity'>15</span> successful inserts: </h5>   
            <table>  
            <tbody>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>Id</th>  
                    <th>LN</th>  
                    <th>FN</th>  
                    <th>MI</th>  
                    <th>Location</th>  
                    <th></th>  
                </tr>  
                </tbody>  
                <tbody>  
                <tr id='15166'><td>15166</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>J</td><td>594491567</td><td><a onclick='deleteClick(15166, "15166")'>Delete?</a></td></tr>  
                <tr id='15165'><td>15165</td><td>Brown</td><td>Charlie</td><td></td><td>594491567</td><td><a onclick='deleteClick(15165, "15165")'>Delete?</a></td></tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table>  
        </div>  
</div>
```

I have this AJAX function that returns a `<tr>` and prepends it to the table:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.post("/ajax/files" , $("#files").serialize(), function(data){
        filesReset();
        if (data != "") {
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last").prepend(data);
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").find("td").hide();
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").show("highlight" , {"color": "aqua"}, 500);
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").find("td").fadeIn(500);

            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:last").remove();
        } else {
            alert("Insufficient criteria for submission.");
            $("#hidden").click();
        }
    });
}
```

I also have an AJAX function that deletes a row:

```
function deleteClick(id, rowId) {
    filesReset();
    $("#" + rowId).css("background-color", "#FBB");

    $.post("/ajax/delete" , { "id": id, "offset": offset} , function(data){
        if (data) {
            $("#" + rowId).hide("explode", 500, function(){
                $("#" + rowId).remove();
                $("#lastInsert table tbody:last").append(data);
                $("#lastInsert table tr:last").effect("highlight", 1500);
            });
        } else {
            $("#" + rowId).find("td").css("color", "black");
            alert("System is unable to delete the specified record.");
        }
    });
}
```

When I use the delete function on the table as it is created on load, everything works as expected. However, when I try to delete a row that I have added as part of the AJAX operation `submitForm()`, everything works fine except that the entire table loses its right border. Here is the PHP function that returns the `<tr>`:

```
class Mess_View_Helper_ViewLastInsertsAsTableRows extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function viewLastInsertsAsTableRows($quantity = 15, $offset = 0, $header = false)
    {
        $filesTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Files();
        $rowset = $filesTable->getLastInserts($quantity, $offset);

        foreach ($rowset as $row) {
            $output .= "<tr id='" . $row['fil_id_pk'] . "'>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['fil_id_pk'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['fil_last_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['fil_first_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['fil_middle_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['fil_box_id_fk'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td><a onclick='deleteClick({$row['fil_id_pk']}, \"" . $row['fil_id_pk'] . "\")'>Delete?</a></td></tr>";
        }

        if ($header) {
            $output =
            "<div id='lastInsert'>
                <h5>Last <span id='quantity'>$quantity</span> successful inserts: </h5>
                <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>LN</th>
                        <th>FN</th>
                        <th>MI</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody>
                    $output
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>";
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Why is the border going away?

Comment: maybe the issue has something to do with table's html, you have two tbody nodes while the first one should be thead

Comment: @ivan just tried that. Didn't affect anything

Comment: I should just mention that I am using firebug and watching the html change as I do this, and there is a strange style attribute that is appearing with the injected tr's: style=''  No idea why this would be happening.

Answer (score 0):

The last line/appendage for $output in your insert function looks suspicious

```
$output .= "<td><a onclick='deleteClick({$row['fil_id_pk']}, \"" . $row['fil_id_pk'] . "\")'>Delete?</a></td></tr>";
```

Seems it should have been

```
$output .= "<td><a onclick='deleteClick(".{$row['fil_id_pk']}.", \"" . $row['fil_id_pk'] . "\")'>Delete?</a></td></tr>";
```

It could have possibly messed up the format of your table.  Just seems weird that it would still remove the row correctly but mess up your format.  In any case, seems worth correcting and seeing if that helps.

Comment: It has looked suspicious to me too on occasion. If I were to correct it the way you suggested, I would have to take out the curly-braces, which just demarcate where code begins and ends, rather than breaking the string up into concatenations.

Comment: ah, i totally ignored the braces.  That would explain why it works... but not the missing border unfortunately.

Comment: Well, one way to fix it would be to just `$("#lastInsert table").css("border-right" , "1px solid #D9D9D9");` but it would be nice to know why this is happening anyway. Haven't tried it in IE yet.